# TabControl DockStyle : Fill

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a `TabControl`, when I choose `DockStyle: Fill`, it begins to fill from 0,0 over the whole parent. How could I change this coordinats for `DockStyle: Fill`?

I work with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
`Fill` means exactly that;; it will fill all available space.

Instead, you can `Anchor` all 4 sides.

If you're trying to put another control next to it, just dock that control to one side.
(you may need to Send to Back)

Comment: on top i have some buttons lower i want to put TabControl but it intersects buttons

Comment: "Instead, you can Anchor all 4 sides. " Thx